# perl package statement and perl module locations

Tags: perl-module

I am writing my first real Perl modules using Moo. But I am getting confused about package locations and package statements and "use".

I have a simple program in c:/temp:

```
use Roadmap::a;
print a->new->aa->[0] . "\n";
```

I have a simple module C:/bin/perl/perl/site/lib/Roadmap/a.pm, @INC has:

```
@INC:
C:/bin/perl/perl/site/lib
C:/bin/perl/perl/vendor/lib
C:/bin/perl/perl/lib
.
```

If a.pm is this:

```
package Roadmap::a;
use Moo;
use Types::Standard qw(ArrayRef);
has aa => (is => 'rw', isa => ArrayRef, default => sub{ [3] });
1;
```

It returns an error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "a" 
(perhaps you forgot to load "a"?) at e.pl line 2.
```

But if a.pm is this:

```
package a;
use Moo;
use Types::Standard qw(ArrayRef);
has aa => (is => 'rw', isa => ArrayRef, default => sub{ [3] });
1;
```

It succeeds and returns the answer '3'. What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't all modules have names of Somedir::Module ?? Thanks!

Update: this is module is simple enough that all I did was create the directory  site/lib/Roadmap and place the a.pm file within it. Should I have instead tried to do some kind of perl module install on this simple module? For this simple example, it didn't seem like I needed to.

Update: if I replace "a->new()" with "Roadmap::a->new()" then my original example works. But I was hoping that with a package Somedir::Module, after doing the "use Somedir::Module" in my script, I could then just do Module->new() instead of Somedir::Module->new().

Update: continuing the conversation with myself, if I change the script to this format, it all works the way I want it to. (Of course I would never use a lowercase module name in practice, this is just for testing.)

```
use aliased 'Roadmap::a';
print a->new->aa->[0] . "\n";
```

So I guess I have now answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

"use aliased" solves the problem nicely.